# Como retornar uma lista de campos específicos em um aggregation no MongoDB

Tags: typescript, mongodb

Olá estou criando uma query genérica conforme o código abaixo:

```js
// dados de exemplo em uma coleção "test" do mongodb
const test = [
  { "name": "foo", age: 2 },
  { "name": "bar", age: 16 },
  { "name": "bin", age: 53 },
]

// tipo esperado na coleção
type Test = {
  name: string
  age: number
}

// resultado esperado nas buscas tipo "search"
type SearchResult<T = any> = {
  total: number
  limit: number
  offset: number
  items: Partial<Array<T>>
}

// aggregation que estou montando
async function searchTest({
  // aqui entra a consulta de dados
  where = {},
  // tamanho maximo da paginacao
  limit = 50,
  // inicio da paginacao
  offset = 0,
  // a ordenacao que sera aplicada
  sort,
  // os campos que devem retornar nos items
  fields
}): Promise<SearchResult<Test>> {
  const agg = [
    // filtra os dados
    { $match: where },
    // se tiver um sort ele ordena
    sort && { $sort: sort },
    // quebra a consulta em 2 pra achar a quantidade total
    // de itens atendidas pela query
    {
      $facet: {
        total: [
          { $count: "total" },
        ],
        items: [
          // pula x itens no offset pra paginação
          { $skip: offset },
          // pega x itens no limit pra paginação
          { $limit: limit },
          // aqui preciso filtrar os campos que forem enviados
          // se forem enviados...
          fields && { /* ???*/ }
        ].filter(x => x)
      }
    }
  ].filter(x => x)

  return await db.getCollect
```

Preciso saber como posso fazer o filtro dos campos que serão retornados nos objetos de forma dinâmica... Se estivermos em SQL poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```js
const fields = 'foo, age'
const sql = `SELECT ${fields}` FROM test`
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seria assim:

```
const fieldsObj: { [key: string]: number} = {}; 
fields.forEach((field)=> fieldsObj[field] = 1)

const agg = [ ...

    items: [  
       // pula x itens no offset pra paginação{ $skip: offset },
       // pega x itens no limit pra paginação
       { $limit: limit },
       // aqui preciso filtrar os campos que forem enviados
       // se forem enviados...
       fields && {$project : fieldsObj },
    ].filter(x => x)
```

Nunca utilizei muito o MongoDB, mais olhando na [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) e esta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419139/aggregate-query-in-mongodb-returns-specific-field), acredito que a chave `$project` e utilizado para descrever os ***fields*** que voce quer ser retornados.  Estou assumindo também que o campo `fields` que voce recebe é um `Array`.

Comment: boa! realmente isso reslve meu problema dos campos q quero retornar

Comment: Aconselho a não usar javascript junto com as query do mongodb. 
isso vc pode fazer em um project como Hozeis comentou. 

utilizando o o filter do proprio mongo.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/